# automatically unmount if the source no longer exists

Tags: mount

I am writing a VPN utility, which adds new entries to `/etc/hosts`.  In order to make things more managable, I try to do a `bind-mount`:

```
mount -o ro,bind myhosts /etc/hosts
```

While the VPN connection is disconnected, I remove `myhosts`, but the content still exists in `/etc/hosts`...

Is it possible to make `myhosts` transient, so that if it vanishes, the mount point is automatically removed and the original `/etc/hosts` is restored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make myhosts transient

not on a VPN connection, without you writing a program that checks whether the connection works and deletes the file if it doesn't.

> and if it vanishes the mount point is automatically removed and original /etc/hosts is restored?

this sounds like a *very* questionable approach. Your VPN client should probably implement [Name Service Switch (NSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch), that's what it's for.

Comment: I checked NSS, it is either too complicated, or not meet my request.   Let's forget about VPN.  What I want is: can umount be automatic if the underlying resource disappears?

Comment: As said in the beginning of my answer: no. Whatever resource you mean, you need to write a program to check that resource's availability and do what you want (unmount) accordingly. Files are no different here: deleting a file doesn't actually make it unavailable to someone still holding an open for handle of it, so you need to watch its path for changes. You have to solve such problems with userland programs.

Comment: And honestly, having had a look at the NSS API you'd need to implement: it's really not that bad?

Comment: Could you please explain, if using NSS API what should I do, and will it be automatic reverted if the VPN connection vanishes.  The reason I am reluctant is that I program in Go, not in C

Comment: I've never written Go, but I think [Go can export C symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c), so that's no inherent problem.You need to implement a NSS [*Service*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extending-NSS.html) (which means shared library), which means you need to implement a setup and teardown function, and the one important function that looks up hosts, `_nss_files_gethostbyname_r`. In that function you check whether you're currently on VPN, and if so, you do one thing (e.g. read the host they asked for from a file), and if not,

Comment: you just return "haven't found it", `NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND`. That's it.

Comment: I found a go wrapper but unfortunately the author abandoned it: https://github.com/protosam/go-libnss

Comment: hm the first line of the Readme says that Go might be the wrong language for this job.